# VSCode / csproj / tasks.json - Adding custom build step

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a VSCode solution consisting a C# project. Part of the C# project is a static website that I build using webpack and `npm run build` would build the website.

I would like to include the website build as a custom build step within the CSPROJ file. How do I do it?

I tried this in the vscode tasks.json file:

```
    {
        "label": "website-build",
        "command": "npm",
        "args": ["run", "build"],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/website"
        }
    },
```

But I got the following error:

```
> Executing task: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm run build <

The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 193).

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but I believe this should work (this should be your tasks.json file... It will have also your other configurations):

(consider to have your package.json in your workingFolder/prova)

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "run build",
            "path": "prova/",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "npm: run build",
            "detail": "install dependencies from package",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work.

> Executing task: npm run "run build" <

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\src\app\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\src\app\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vvg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-20T06_26_12_402Z-debug.log
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\Sysnative\cmd.exe /d /c npm run "run build"" ter...

Comment: It looks like I may have to specify the location of the package.json (since it lies in a different folder relative to the .csproj file)